# Stored Procedure returns an Empty Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute the following command which executes a stored procedure:

`exec FSDBMR.dbo.usp_zPlannedOrder 16352705, 0.0000, 'Y'`

However it returns an empty table as:

[image]

However when I execute the stored procedure through a web application, it does return a result, but not when I run it with SQL Server Management Studio.

How can I run a Stored Procedure and get the results its supposed to return? There is nothing wrong with the stored procedure, but just in case:

```
USE [FSDBMR]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_zPlannedOrder]    Script Date: 07/08/2015 15:46:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_zPlannedOrder]


 @anReportInstanceID      int
,@afmultiplier            float
,@DeleteTempData          varchar(1) = 'Y'                    -- 'Y' means delete the temp data

as

select im.ItemNumber
      ,case 
       when im.MakeBuyCode = 'M' 
       then im.Planner
       else im.Buyer
       end as PlannerBuyer  -- two type, 'C' and 'S'
      ,imd.ReplanCode
      ,im.LastPeriodReviewDate   ReplanDate
      ,im.ItemDescription
      ,im.ItemUM
      ,im.ItemRevision
      ,im.MakeBuyCode
      ,im.ItemType
      ,im.ItemStatus
      ,im.OrderPolicy
      ,im.IsInspectionRequired
      ,im.DecimalPrecision
      ,imd.OnHandQuantity
      ,case
       when rsd.SupplyDemandType = 'D' or rsd.SupplyDemandType = 'S' 
       then convert(char(1),rsd.StartForecastPeriod) 
       else '' 
       end StartForecastPeriod
      ,case 
       when rsd.SupplyDemandType = 'I' 
       then null 
       else rsd.RequiredDate
       end RequiredDate
      ,case 
       when rsd.SupplyDemandType = 'D' 
       then rsd.GrossRequiredFlag
       else null
       end GrossRequiredFlag
      ,case rsd.PlannedOrderQuantity
       when 0
       then case rsd.SupplyDemandType
            when 'D'
            then rsd.GrossRequiredQuantity * @afmultiplier
            else null 
            end
       else null
       end GrossRequiredQuantity
      ,case rsd.PlannedOrderQuantity
       when 0
       then case rsd.SupplyDemandType
            when 'S'
            then rsd.ScheduledReceiptQuantity * @afmultiplier
            else null 
            end
       else null
       end ScheduledReceiptQuantity
      ,rsd.ProjectedAvailableQuantity * @afmultiplier ProjectedAvailableQuantity
      ,case rsd.PlannedOrderQuantity
       when 0 then null
       else rsd.PlannedOrderQuantity * @afmultiplier
       end PlannedOrderQuantity
      ,case 
       when rsd.SupplyDemandType = 'P' 
       then 'P'--'CUSTOM PROD INV'
       else rsd.PeggingInformation
       end PeggingType
      ,rsd.MessageCount Messages
      ,rsd.SupplyDemandKey SuperKey
from FS_Item im (readuncommitted)
join FS_ItemData imd  (readuncommitted) on (im.ItemKey = imd.ItemKey)
left join FSDBMRTemp.dbo.FS_ReportSDASupplyDemand rsd  (readuncommitted) on im.ItemKey = rsd.ItemKey

where rsd.ReportInstanceKey =@anReportInstanceID 

order by ItemNumber, RequiredDate, TopLevelDemandKey, SupplyDemandType desc, rsd.SupplyDemandKey


-- delete Instance from FS_ReportSDASupplyDemand and FS_ReportSDASupplyDemand table
-- the 3rd parameter for usp_ReportDeleteInstance is for SequenceNo,we do not need here
exec usp_ReportDeleteInstance @anReportInstanceID, null , null

return
```

Comment: Do you have access to the profiler?  if so, run a trace and verify both methods (web and SSMS) are calling the same version of the same stored procedure with the same parameters.

Comment: It also seems like the end of your proc deletes the Report Instance which would not allow you to re-run the proc with the same parameters. Are you sure that `@anReportInstanceID` is created prior to running from SQL?

Comment: Fourth Shift, eh?  Old School.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the stored procedure is being executed on the same instance/sql server database the web version is running on. It may be the case data might be there on one server and not on other!